# xrdp session doesn't start window manager

Tags: 22.04, xrdp, hyper-v

I'm running 22.04.2LTS in a Hyper-V VM on my Windows 10 Desktop.  Since upgrading from 20.04, I can' t run in Enhanced mode, which uses xrdp.  Basic mode runs fine, the desktop starts up and everything works.  But when I try to connect to xrdp in Enhanced mode, I get the signon perfectly okay, but once I log in, I get a blank blue-green screen with nothing on it and it just hangs there; I have a mouse cursor but clicking does nothing.  The Window manager doesn't have any troubles starting up in Basic mode (which goes straight to the console).  Losing Enhanced mode is very inconvenient (smaller screen, no cut and paste with Windows, etc.).  I've tried several things but have been unable to get the window manager to start up in xrdp.  I don't have clue as to what's happening, so if someone could give me some hints, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by purging out xrdp and re-installing it (had to purge to get rid of all the config files).  Had to put back in the change I had made earlier to /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini of port=3389 to vsock=://-1:3389 in order for Hyper-V to successfully connect to the xrdp service, but forcing the change to an (almost) all-stock configuration persuaded a window manager to come up.  Can't say I like how it's setting up the Ubuntu window manager at this point, but the major problem's out of the way and I can tweak that later.